# Issues installing Ubuntu on fresh hard drive

Tags: system-installation

Hard drive crashed on my 4+ year-old laptop.  Decided to try Ubuntu 12.04 desktop instead of reinstalling Vista.  Installed a new 500 GB drive in the laptop, and booted using a newly created Ubuntu flash drive.  Used gparted to create a single ext4 partition.  Rebooted, then tried the "Install to hard drive" option that came up during the boot process.  I got a btrfs message, then a checksumming message, then a series of repeating "asking for cache data failed" and "Assuming drive cache: write through" messages.

Can anyone tell me what these messages mean?  How do I get past this problem?

Comment: I checked those posts, but none of them really help me out.  I also tried to use the graphical installer, but it doesn't work.  I get the Welcome screen with the list of languages down the left side, but the Try & Install icons and buttons aren't displayed for me.  Eventually I get a message saying that Ubiquity crashed.  Is there something special that I need to do if Windows hasn't been installed yet?

Comment: I believe that your HDD *"crashed"* (ie. do not work anymore). The way to get pass through is buying a new HDD.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Please see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167343/what-is-a-asking-for-cache-data-failed-warninga) question.

May be you trying to install Ubuntu on usb stick?

Comment: I saw that post yesterday, which sort of explains what that message means.  Unfortunately, it doesn't tell me what to do about it, or how to get past it.  My intent is to install Ubuntu on my hard drive.  Do you think I'm inadvertently attempting to install Ubuntu to the USB stick instead?  If so, how do I direct the installation to the hard drive?