# SD card reader sometimes not detected

Tags: kernel, realtek, sd-card, card-reader

I have realtek SD Card reader on ubuntu, and something weird happens:
Sometimes it recognises SD card, sometimes it has no action at all after putting it inside, and sometimes shows, disappears then shows and then disappears and so on, here's dmesg when it happens:

```
[  705.838650] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[  706.414218] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[  706.430772] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  707.633972] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[  707.662063] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  707.831366] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[  707.889873] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[  707.918216] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  708.209589] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[  708.400918] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  708.400923] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  708.400927] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  708.400930] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  708.400934] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  708.465062] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[  708.465154] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  708.465156] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[  708.477041] scsi4 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  708.477213] usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-realtek
[  709.475917] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  709.477769] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  710.131709] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  710.132653] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  710.132660] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  710.133694] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  710.133703] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  710.137908] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  710.137916] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  710.140549]  sdb:
[  710.143263] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  710.143273] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  710.143282] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  711.981919] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[  758.520811] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[  803.770458] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[  864.246875] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  868.352881] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[  869.076446] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[  869.093016] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  869.292653] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
[  869.320734] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  869.520610] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci_hcd
[  869.711736] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  869.711741] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  869.711745] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  869.711748] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  869.711752] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  869.727659] scsi5 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  870.298259] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[  870.528192] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci_hcd
[  870.556400] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  870.852071] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
[  870.955243] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  870.955255] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  870.955264] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  870.955270] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  870.955275] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  870.972619] scsi6 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  871.321878] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[  871.519682] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci_hcd
[  871.864317] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  871.864323] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  871.864327] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  871.864331] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  871.864334] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  871.880379] scsi7 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  872.881868] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  872.883394] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  873.537359] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  873.538175] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  873.538182] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  873.539099] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  873.539107] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  873.543066] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  873.543074] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  873.545698]  sdb:
[  873.548954] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  873.548964] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  873.548973] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  874.904666] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[  875.138300] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci_hcd
[  875.377589] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  875.377597] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  875.377602] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  875.377606] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  875.377611] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  875.395620] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  876.396676] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  876.398308] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  877.050200] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  877.050941] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  877.050944] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  877.051688] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  877.051692] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  877.055466] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  877.055474] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  877.057980]  sdb:
[  877.060539] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  877.060543] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  877.060547] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  881.302111] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 16
[  881.503917] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci_hcd
[  881.532168] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  882.011722] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci_hcd
[  882.357797] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  882.357809] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  882.357818] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  882.357825] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  882.357833] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  882.374033] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  882.581646] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 18
[  882.811432] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci_hcd
[  882.914521] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  882.914531] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  882.914537] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  882.914542] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  882.914547] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  882.930544] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  883.929510] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  883.931691] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  884.587645] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  884.588629] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  884.588638] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  884.589669] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  884.589676] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  884.593775] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  884.593783] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  884.596418]  sdb:
[  884.599118] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  884.599128] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  884.599137] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  903.309949] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[  903.607560] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using ehci_hcd
[  903.710767] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  903.710776] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  903.710782] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  903.710787] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  903.710792] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  903.727273] scsi11 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  904.729854] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  904.731947] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  905.383762] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  905.384680] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  905.384689] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  905.385534] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  905.385541] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  905.389363] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  905.389370] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  905.392128]  sdb:
[  905.395004] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  905.395013] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  905.395022] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  910.475095] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 20
[  910.676778] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 21 using ehci_hcd
[  910.780962] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[  910.797126] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  911.060764] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 23 using ehci_hcd
[  911.164100] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  911.164105] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  911.164109] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  911.164112] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  911.164115] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  911.180142] scsi12 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  912.178906] scsi 12:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  912.180483] sd 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  912.971100] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  912.971950] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  912.971958] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  912.972797] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  912.972806] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  912.976876] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  912.976883] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  912.979529]  sdb:
[  912.982396] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  912.982404] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  912.982410] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  913.545862] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 23
[  913.603007] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 480) failed
[  913.603014] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 481) failed
[  913.603017] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 482) failed
[  913.603020] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 483) failed
[  913.603022] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 484) failed
[  913.603025] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 485) failed
[  913.603028] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 486) failed
[  913.603031] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 487) failed
[  913.603039] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 488) failed
[  913.603041] FAT-fs (sdb): Directory bread(block 489) failed
[  913.751579] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci_hcd
[  913.854799] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  913.854809] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  913.854815] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  913.854820] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  913.854825] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  913.870512] scsi13 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  914.870204] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  914.871962] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  915.527587] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  915.528573] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  915.528580] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  915.529465] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  915.529472] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  915.533706] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  915.533714] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  915.536351]  sdb:
[  915.538993] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  915.539003] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  915.539011] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  917.128586] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 24
[  917.330211] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci_hcd
[  917.433880] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  917.433889] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  917.433895] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  917.433901] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  917.433905] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  917.450314] scsi14 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  918.152346] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 25
[  918.413983] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci_hcd
[  918.517339] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  918.517348] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  918.517354] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  918.517359] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  918.517364] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  918.533915] scsi15 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  919.536259] scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  919.537814] sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  920.189983] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  920.190811] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  920.190821] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  920.191861] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  920.191868] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  920.195942] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  920.195949] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  920.198574]  sdb:
[  920.201426] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  920.201434] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  920.201440] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  932.994597] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 26
[  933.196287] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using ehci_hcd
[  933.299609] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  933.299615] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  933.299619] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  933.299622] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  933.299625] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  933.339045] scsi16 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  933.506400] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 27
[  933.704217] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 28 using ehci_hcd
[  933.732609] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  934.088091] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 29 using ehci_hcd
[  934.434187] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  934.434193] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  934.434197] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  934.434200] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  934.434204] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  934.450163] scsi17 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  935.449929] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  935.450619] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  936.106902] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  936.107769] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  936.107772] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  936.108514] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  936.108517] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  936.111920] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  936.111927] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  936.114566]  sdb:
[  936.120989] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  936.120995] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  936.120998] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  939.903949] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 29
[  940.357576] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 30 using ehci_hcd
[  940.548747] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  940.548753] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  940.548757] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  940.548760] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  940.548763] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  940.564895] scsi18 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  941.563859] scsi 18:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  941.565702] sd 18:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  942.221437] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  942.222225] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  942.222234] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  942.223081] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  942.223090] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  942.227301] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  942.227307] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  942.229878]  sdb:
[  942.232467] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  942.232478] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  942.232488] sd 18:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  946.465135] ieee80211 phy0: START: tid 1 is not agg'able
[  949.372674] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 30
[  949.574100] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 31 using ehci_hcd
[  950.061699] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 31, error -71
[  950.078446] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  950.277818] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 33 using ehci_hcd
[  950.306029] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
[  950.593773] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 34 using ehci_hcd
[  950.939790] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0159
[  950.939794] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  950.939797] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0-CRW
[  950.939799] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[  950.939801] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 20071114173400000
[  950.955354] scsi19 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[  951.955469] scsi 19:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic- Multi-Card       1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  951.957130] sd 19:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  952.612802] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] 3862528 512-byte logical blocks: (1.97 GB/1.84 GiB)
[  952.613507] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  952.613511] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  952.614258] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  952.614262] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  952.619391] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  952.619397] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  952.621895]  sdb:
[  952.625756] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  952.625761] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  952.625765] sd 19:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Any help?

Sometimes when it doesnt see, it writes such error in dmesg:

```
[ 1373.209390] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 37 using ehci_hcd
[ 1373.860861] usb 1-1.2: device not accepting address 37, error -71
[ 1373.877631] hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 nowadays. I have no error message but each time I insert a SD(HC) card it does not mount, anywhere. I don't think it's a hardware problem since same devices worked with ubuntu 13.10 helped by these :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925760/comments/75

[Errors in dmesg - Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132100/errors-in-dmesg-test-wp-failed-assume-write-enabled)

May it help ?